# Text to PDF Positioning Lines

Tags: python

I have a text file that i am reading and writing line by line into a PDF. The lines are out of position on the PDF because the FPDF library is left aligning all my lines. I am using the property set x so i can position each line to my liking. I am trying to reposition the headers until "RATE CODE CY" the would like all the data under the columns to come after. Then another header appears. I would like to align all the headers that come after the data. I know a for loop needs to be done to bring rest of the data...the issue is a header will come again and there is where i have to make the change with set_x property.

```
pdf = FPDF("L", "mm", "A4")
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('arial', style='', size=10.0)
lines = file.readlines()
header8 = lines[7]
header8_1 = " ".join(lines[8].split()[:4])
header8_2 = " ".join(lines[8].split()[4:])
header9_1 = " ".join(lines[9].split()[:5])
header9_2 = " ".join(lines[9].split()[5:])


pdf.cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=header8_1, border=0)
pdf.set_x(125)
pdf.cell(ln=1, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=header8_2, border=0)
pdf.cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=header9_1, border=0)
pdf.set_x(125)
pdfcell(ln=1, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=header9_2, border=0)
```

Current PDF file:

```
READ SVC B MAXIMUM TOTAL DUE METER NO REMARKS
ACCOUNT # SERVICE ADDRESS CITY DATE DAY C KWH KWD AMOUNT
RATE CODE CY CUSTOMER NAME MAILING ADDRESS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11211-22222 12345 TEST HWY #86 TITUSVIL 10/12/19 29 C 1,444 189.01 ABC1234
GS-1 3 Home & ASSOC INC 1234 Miami HWY APT49
22222-33333 12345 TEST HWY #88 TITUSVIL 10/04/19 29 C 256 41.50 ABC1235
GS-1 3 DGN & ASSOC INC 1234 Miami HWY APT49
READ SVC B MAXIMUM TOTAL DUE METER NO REMARKS
ACCOUNT # SERVICE ADDRESS CITY DATE DAY C KWH KWD AMOUNT
RATE CODE CY CUSTOMER NAME MAILING ADDRESS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11211-22222 12345 TEST HWY #86 TITUSVIL 10/12/19 29 C 1,444 189.01 ABC1234
GS-1 3 Home & ASSOC INC 1234 Miami HWY APT49
22222-33333 12345 TEST HWY #88 TITUSVIL 10/04/19 29 C 256 41.50 ABC1235
GS-1 3 DGN & ASSOC INC 1234 Miami HWY APT49
```